# Pandas: Convert dataframe to dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1, col2
A      0
A      1
B      2
C      3
```

I would like to get this:

```
{ A: [0,1], B: [2], C: [3] }
```

I tried:

```
df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()
```

but that is not quite correct. The first issue I have is 'A' is repeated, I end up getting A:1 only (0 gets overwritten). How to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension on a groupby.

```
>>> {idx: group['col2'].tolist() 
     for idx, group in df.groupby('col1')}
{'A': [0, 1], 'B': [2], 'C': [3]}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Solution

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict()

{'A': [0, 1], 'B': [2], 'C': [3]}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Are you able to add a bit more explanation on why/how it works? Thanks again